# JIT Debugger dialog window is not showing after starting a service

Tags: c#, windows-services, jit

I am currently working on a windows service, after installing the service via installutil.exe, as I start the service in services.msc there's no JIT window indication if I would want to debug it or not.

And once the service is running and tried the "Attached to process" in visual studio, It will say an error like **Unable to attach to the process. Visual Studio has insufficient privileges to debug this process. To debug this process, Visual Studio must be run as an administrator**. Eventhough I'm an administrator in my Local.

My problem is similar in this thread on [MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/7bb307b8-fe8e-4eb5-ad0a-f76c9f7f8ca7/).
But I am using Visual Studio 2008. I've tried all possible solution after posting this questiion here.

I've tried

- adding `<system.windows.forms jitdebugging=true/>` to my config file
- checking Tools->Options->Debugging
- checking registry settings
- run visual studio 2008 as administrator, attached the process and still throwing the insufficient priveleges error.

Any ideas?
I Hope someone could help me.

Thanks,
Sherwin

Answer (score 0):

Just do what the error message is saying -- run Visual Studio as administrator. To do that, right click on Visual Studio icon in start menu and select option "Run as administrator".

Comment: Hi, as I stated above, I have already done that. Anyone who'll see that error would do that. Thanks.